# How to break caching on exist-db of included XSLs in Transform

Tags: xslt, xquery, exist-db

I have a large set of XSLs that we recently went through and implemented a shared XSL template with common bits. We included an xsl:include in all the main XSLs now to pull these in. We had no issues at first until we started to make changes to the shared XSL.

For information, the whole system is web based, calling queries to dynamically format documents in the database given different XSLs through XSL FO and RenderX.

The main transform is:

```
let $fo := util:expand(transform:transform($articles, doc("/db/Customer/data/edit/xsl/Custbatch.xsl"), $parameters))
```

That XSL (Custbatch.xsl) has:

```
<xsl:include href="Custshared.v1.xsl"/>
```

If we make an edit to "Custshared.v1.xsl" is not reflected in the result because it is obvious that "Custshared.v1.xsl" is being cached and used. We know this because as you can see the name now includes "v1". If we make a change and change all the references say from v1 to v2, it all works. But this seems a bit ridiculous as that means we have to change the 18 XSLs that include this XSL or do something silly like restart the database.

So, what am I missing in the setup or controller.xql (which has the following on all not matched paths), to get things not to cache. I assume that is all internal so this setting likely does not matter. Is there some other setting in the config that does?

```
<dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
    <cache-control cache="no"/>
</dispatch>
```

In reading the document here: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform.xml, it states:

"The stylesheet will be compiled into a template using the standard Java APIs (javax.xml.transform). The template is shared between all instances of the function and will only be reloaded if modified since its last invocation."

However, if I change an included XSL, it is not being used.

**Update #1**

I even went as far as creating a query that returns the XSL that is included, then I use:

```
<xsl:include href="http://localhost/get-include-xsl.xq"/>
```

This does work as formatting is not broken, but changing the underlying XSL yields the same result. So even that Xquery result is cached.

**Update #2**

And yes, through some simple test all is proven.
If I make any change to the root template (like add a meaningless space) and run, it does include the changes made in the include. If I **only** change the included XSL, no changes happen.

So lacking anything else, we could always write a Xquery that basically touches all the main templates after a change is made to the include template. Seems so wrong as a workaround.

**Update #3**

So the workaround we are currently using is that we have an unused "variable" in the XSL (version) and when we update the shared template, we execute that query which basically updates the value in that variable. At least it's only one XQuery and maybe we should attach to a trigger.

Comment: What version of eXist-db are you using? The mechanism for caching XSLT's was changed recently.

Comment: I believe 2.2, 

#eXist build info
project.version=2.2
project.built=20141120124006
scm.branch=master
scm.revision=5c5aadc

Comment: I don't find this behaviour particularly surprising: it's very common for web services that include XSLT processing to compile a stylesheet on first reference and then reuse the compiled stylesheet if the same source URI is used again. Whether there's any way to clear this cache, or suppress the caching altogether, I simply don't know.

Comment: Yes @MichaelKay, I guess I am not surprised either. The compile of the template likely does not look for changes in any includes and hence the issue.

Comment: @KevinBrown Could you do an experiment with eXist 3.4.1? The caching mechanism there was revised. If you still have the same issue, please open an issue on our github.

Comment: @adamretter, I can but it will be probably a month at least. We are in release schedule and then vacations so after that yes. Plans are going to 3+ version and also engaging support. I must say exist-db is very impressive and should be supported!

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in `$exist-db-root$/conf.xml` for the XSL transformer where you can turn off caching: `<transformer class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" caching="no">` (The default is 'yes')